# Default value for checkbox in WordPress API Settings

Tags: wordpress

I'm using the WordPress Options API to handle my plugin options. However I would like to have a checkbox enabled by default but cannot figure out why. I've added the line `'default' => '1','value' => '1',` to my code but it's not working. Aloso red the documentation on https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/settings/settings-api/. Any pointers or documentation?

Here's my complete code:

```
<?php

// orgname SETTINGS PAGE
class orgname_eperience_settings {

    /** @var string $capability */
    private $capability = 'manage_options';
    
    // 1. Modules
    private $fields_modules = [
        [
            'id' => 'mod_maintenance',
            'label' => 'Maintenance',
            'description' => '',
            'type' => 'checkbox',
            // DOENS"T WORK FFS
            'default' => '1',
            'value' => '1',
        ],
    ];

    // CONSTRUCT SETINGS
    function __construct() {
        add_action( 'admin_init', [$this, 'settings_init'] );
        add_action( 'admin_menu', [$this, 'options_page'] );
    }

    // REGISTER SETTINGS AND FIELDS
    function settings_init() : void {

        // 2. REGISTER SETTINGS - Modules
        register_setting(
            'orgname-mymodsmodules',
            'be_modules'
        );

        // 3. REGISTER SECTION - Modules
        add_settings_section(
            'orgname-mymodssection-modules',
            __( 'Setup your mods', 
            'orgname-mymodsmodules' ), // SECTIE OMSCHRIJVING
            [$this, 'render_section'],
            'orgname-mymodsmodules'
        );
            

        // 4. REGISTER FIELDS - Modules
        foreach( $this->fields_modules as $field_modules ) {
            add_settings_field(
                $field_modules['id'],
                __( $field_modules['label'], 'orgname-mymodsmodules' ),
                [$this, 'render_field_modules'],
                'orgname-mymodsmodules',
                'orgname-mymodssection-modules',
                [
                    'label_for' => $field_modules['id'],
                    'class' => 'wporg_row',
                    'field' => $field_modules,
                ]
            );
        }                                                                                                   
    }

    // ADD MENU ITEM
    function options_page() : void {
        add_submenu_page(
            'options-general.php', /* Parent Menu Slug */
            'orgname | Experience', /* Page Title */
            'orgname', /* Menu Title */
            $this->capability, /* Capability */
            'orgname-experience', /* Menu Slug */
            [$this, 'render_options_page'], /* Callback */
        );
    }

    // ADD OPTIONS PAGE
    function render_options_page() : void {

        // check user capabilities
        if ( ! current_user_can( $this->capability ) ) {
            return;
        }

        $default_tab = null;
        $tab = isset($_GET['tab']) ? $_GET['tab'] : $default_tab;

        // HTML OPTIONS PAGE
        include BE_PLUGIN_PATH . 'options.php';
    }

    // Modules
    function render_field_modules( array $args ) : void {
        $field = $args['field'];
        $options = get_option( 'be_modules' );
        switch ( $field['type'] ) {
            case "checkbox": {
                ?>
                <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    id="<?php echo esc_attr( $field['id'] ); ?>"
                    name="be_modules[<?php echo esc_attr( $field['id'] ); ?>]"
                    value="1"
                    <?php echo isset( $options[ $field['id'] ] ) ? ( checked( $options[ $field['id'] ], 1, false ) ) : ( '' ); ?>
                    
                >
                <p class="description">
                    <?php esc_html_e( $field['description'], 'orgname-mymodsmodules' ); ?>
                </p>
                <?php
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    
    /**
     * Render a section on a page, with an ID and a text label.
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     *
     * @param array $args {
     *     An array of parameters for the section.
     *
     *     @type string $id The ID of the section.
     * }
     */
    function render_section( array $args ) : void {
        ?>
        <p id="<?php echo esc_attr( $args['id'] ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( '', 'orgname-experience' ); ?></p>
        <?php
    }

}

new orgname_eperience_settings();
```